# featherlight.js gallery swipe touch enabled disables mouse navigation

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I made a gallery using featherlight.gallery.js and followed the instructions (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#featherlight-gallery) on including swipe/touch support by loading jquery detect_swipe.js.

The problem is that I want to have swipe/touch and mouse click navigation at the same time and for some reason it goes one way or the other. If I'm on a tablet PC, I don't necessarily want to swipe even if I can because maybe I'm using my mouse to navigate.

I created a fiddle with the detect_swipe.js file where it works with touch but not mouse:

http://jsfiddle.net/scotsscripts/JNsu6/213/

This is the example featherlight gallery fiddle without touch enabled (copy of featherlight "official example"):

http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/15/

The HTML is super basic, the only thing that changes is whether or not detect_Swipe.js is loaded:

```
<h3>Gallery</h3>
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
  <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_b.jpg"><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_3403152632_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_f652202d1b_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_q.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Any ideas why mouse and touch don't work together? Any easy fixes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at an [upcoming change](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/pull/237) that would probably resolve your issue